# What is Dynamic Typing?

Tags: php, dynamic, typing

I've heard this term used with scripting languages such as PHP. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language

Comment: @DanielA.White: That article really isn't very good at explaining.

Comment: also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing

Answer (score 20):

Dynamic typing is a definitive characteristic of a language. A short explanation might be:

> A language has dynamic typing when it does not associate values
>   strictly with a specific type,  but it is designed to "decide" what
>   the type of a value should be at runtime, based on how you are attempting to use it.

For example, in PHP you can write

```
$count = "5"; // defines a string variable
```

and then go on to say

```
$count = $count * 2; // this is legal and has the obvious result¹
```

What happened here? For one, the compiler did not complain that you are attempting to multiply a string by a number and refuse to compile the program (such as would happen in languages like C, C++, C# and Java). It produced code to forward the arguments `$count` and `2` to the multiplication operator just like you asked and moved on.

With the program now compiled, dynamic typing comes into effect *at runtime*. When the multiplication operator gets around to look at its operands, it checks to see what is the current, if you will, type of each one. As before, it's a string and an int. But the operator knows that it can only multiply two integers (let's ignore floats for simplicity), so it has to somehow produce an integer value from the string. All dynamically typed languages have [rules that stipulate how such a conversion works](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) between all pairs of value types; in this case, PHP [produces the integer 5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) from the string "5".

Another aspect of dynamic typing you might come across is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing); this only applies to values of class types (i.e. not primitives). In short, duck typing stipulates that when you write

```
$object->quack();
```

the compiler will not attempt to see if `$object` is of a type that has a method named `quack` that takes no arguments. Rather, it will attempt at runtime to see if `$object` actually has such a method; if it does, the method will be called regardless of what type 
of object we have at hand (might be a duck, might be a dog for all the compiler cares).

**Footnotes:**

¹ Multiplying a string by an integer is what *dynamic typing* is all about (producing an integer from a string because the multiplication demands one); however, there is also *loose typing* at work here (allowing the multiplication to compile without being able to prove that both operands are actually ints).

Comment: What about static typed languages that support inheritance on operators?

Comment: @hakre: In a nutshell, operator overloading allows languages that are statically typed to pretend they are not. You may be able to write `array * 5` in C++ because `operator*` is overloaded, but you are doing all the work explicitly. In principle, you could just as well use C and write `array * array_fill(array_copy(array), 5)` -- you still have to supply the code.

Comment: You're describing *weak* typing, not *dynamic* typing. Dynamic typing is where types are associated with values instead of variables. Dynamically typed languages can be full of implicit conversions, like PHP and Javascript, but they can also reject implicit conversions, like Python.