# PHP Object Dynamic Binding, Does such term exist?

Tags: php, class, dynamic-binding

I know that if $var is NEVER declared, it can be declared WITH a sub-object like $var->mysubvar=1;
But if $var = “123” is mentioned ahead of time, then $var->mysubvar=1 will cause error. As it is declared ahead of time

I heard it was named "Dynamic Binding". But when I actually look into the term, I can not really find such description inside PHP Manual that match with this scenario and behavior.

Is this behavior call "Dynamic Binding"? Is there a specific name for it. But if it is the name then why PHP Manual did not include such technique or behavior?

The question is that What is the name to describe such behavior that one does not need to declare object ahead of time and an object will be automatically generated if there is sub-object is declared. (for example, javascript will not allow to manipulate an object without doing var myvar=1 (or equivalent), first.)

Answer:
Ah yea, its indeed deal with dynamic typing.
[What is Dynamic Typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394711/what-is-dynamic-typing)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I think it has more to do with dynamic *typing* than dynamic binding.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you mentioned is related to dynamic typing, not necessarily dynamic binding.  The [PHP documentation on variable types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) covers this.

> The type of a variable is not usually set by the programmer; rather, it is decided at runtime by PHP depending on the context in which that variable is used.

The reason your examples throw errors is because of a type mismatch.
For example, assuming `$var` isn't set, executing `$var->mysubvar = 1` will create `$var` as an *object*.  Attempting to follow it with `$var = 5` will result in an error because your previous command specified that `$var` will be an object, not a scalar.