# How to solve cannot use string offset as an array error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to add multiple data into table at once but my code gives an error saying 'cannot use string offset as an array'. I have attached my code. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
$issuedate=$_POST['issuedate'];
$member=$_POST['member'];
$bno[0]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno'];
$bno[1]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno1'];
$bno[2]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno2'];
$bno[3]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno4'];                        
$returndate = $_POST['returndate'];

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $sql5 = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO borrow(TitleNo,MemberID,IssueDate,dueDate,ReturnDate) VALUES ('".$bno[$i]['TitleNo']."','$member','$issuedate','$returndate')");
}

if ($sql5)
{
    echo '<h4 class="message">Add New Book Copies! </h4>'; // echo $test;   
}
else
{
    echo 'Fail.';
}
```

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: You could make your life easier using arrays for the name attributes of your inputs as well. And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: looks like `$bno` had the string assigned to it instead of array before this code.

Comment: For start ... start watching videos (like Laracast) and reading tutorials for clear and reusable code!  
On other hand ... just add "$bno = array();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set **$bno** as string in some previous code.
What you can do for a quick fix is:

1. change **$bno** to somehing else, for example **$book**

```
$book[0]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno'];  
$book[1]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno1'];
//..
```

2. set **$bno** to a new array and then assign the values

```
$bno = array();
$bno[0]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno'];  
$bno[1]['TitleNo'] = $_POST['bno1'];  
//...
```

***Additional Notes***

By the way it's better to escape somehow the values you enter in your DB. You can use **mysqli_real_escape_string**

Just assign do this for all the values:

```
$bno[0]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bno']);
```

**Sources to read**

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

You are probably assigning string to `$bno` variable thus it dynamically becomes of type `string`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394711/what-is-dynamic-typing). Regarding the example you should

1. `$bno = array();`
2. Escape all your DB inputs (or even better, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php))
3. It makes more sense to put the `if..else` inside the `for` loop

Thus

```
$bno = array();

$mysqli_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "schema");

$issuedate = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['issuedate']);
$member = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['member']);
$bno[0]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['bno']);
$bno[1]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['bno1']);
$bno[2]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['bno2']);
$bno[3]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['bno4']);                        
$returndate = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['returndate']);

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO borrow(TitleNo,MemberID,IssueDate,dueDate,ReturnDate) VALUES ('".$bno[$i]['TitleNo']."','".$member."','".$issuedate."','".$returndate."')");

    if ($sql)
    {
        echo '<h4 class="message">Add New Book Copies! </h4>'; // echo $test;   
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Fail.';
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your code. When using mysqli_real_escape_string in procedural style you should pass the DB instance.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string is used wrong!  Please check documentation and fix your code.

Comment: Sorry, was typing at the speed of thoughts. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look att [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) and [bind params](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). When you're doing the insert statements you select five columns and only inserts four values.

```
 $sql5 = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO borrow(TitleNo,MemberID,IssueDate,dueDate,ReturnDate) VALUES ('".$bno[$i]['TitleNo']."','$member','$issuedate','$returndate')");
```

And as @jeroen mentioned, your code has sql-injection problems, read more about sql-injection [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

I've created and exampel using prepared statements and bind params. Note:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssss',$bno[$i]['TitleNo'], $member, $issuedate, $dueDate, $returndate);
```

'sssss' are just for demo purpose, I assume dueDate and returndate columns are datetime something simular.

```
$DBServer = 'localhost';
$DBUser  = 'root';
$DBPass = 'root';
$DBName = 'borrow';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

$sql = ' INSERT INTO borrow (TitleNo,MemberID,IssueDate,dueDate,ReturnDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';

$TitleNo = $bno[0]['TitleNo'];
$member = 'MemberID';
$issuedate = 'issuedate';
$dueDate = 'dueDate';
$returndate = 'returndate';

/* Prepare statement */
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}


for( $i= 0; $i < count($bno); $i++){
/* Bind parameters. s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$stmt->bind_param('sssss',$bno[$i]['TitleNo'], $member, $issuedate, $dueDate, $returndate);

/* Execute statement */
$stmt->execute();
}
if( $stmt->affected_rows > 0 ){
    echo '<h4 class="message">Add New Book Copies!</h4>';
}

$stmt->close();
```

However im not sure if it's best practice to do a mass insert to db using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Initialising your array (ie, $bno was probably initialised to a string in your code which caused the error you are seeing), escaping the input and doing a single INSERT (rather than 4, where you only check the results of the last one):-

```
<?php 
$bno = array();
$sql_array = array();
$issuedate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['issuedate']);
$member = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['member']);
$bno[0]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bno']);
$bno[1]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bno1']);
$bno[2]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bno2']);
$bno[3]['TitleNo'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bno4']);                        
$returndate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['returndate']);

foreach($bno AS $abno)
{
    $sql_array = "('".$bno['TitleNo']."','$member','$issuedate','$returndate')"
}
$sql5 = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO borrow(TitleNo,MemberID,IssueDate,dueDate,ReturnDate)
        VALUES ".implode(', ', $sql_array));            
if ($sql5) 
{
    echo '<h4 class="message">Add New Book Copies!</h4>';
    // echo $test;
} 
else
{
    echo 'Fail.';
}
```

This does suggest that the database could be further normalised, as you have multiple rows being inserted that are identical except for one value.